# How do I log a message from Javascript called by Camel?

Tags: javascript, logging, apache-camel

I am calling a Javascript file from Apache Camel XML DSL running inside Apache ServiceMix as follows:

```
<endpoint id="myJavascript" uri="language:javascript:file:data/myJavascript.js"/>
...
<to ref="myJavascript"/>
...
```

I want to log a message from inside myJavascript.js so that the message shows up in the main Camel Context log.

The Camel doc [here](http://camel.apache.org/javascript.html) indicates that the CamelContext Java object is passed through. I was hoping it would include a getter for the logger so that I could do something like this within the script:

```
var log = context.getLog();
log.debug("Some debug log message");
```

However, there is no reference to a logger (I noted a getter for a Debugger and an Interceptor though) so it looks like I'm out of luck.

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer buried deep inside this article [here](http://grokbase.com/t/camel/users/141a1mw2vd/looking-for-a-way-to-run-javascript-in-camel-and-set-message-headers).

I just needed to add the following to my Javascript:

```
var LOG = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(exchange.getFromRouteId());
```

This uses the Camel Exchange From Route Id as the log name, but you could use the script name instead.

Then I can call the logger as follows and the messages end up in the main Camel logger:

```
LOG.info("Log message at INFO level");
LOG.debug("Log message at DEBUG level");
```